# Using google material icons in preact/react app

Tags: reactjs, material-design, preact

I'm building a preact application. In where, I use material-components-web.
If I render a icon like this

```
<i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">home</i>
```

It works fine and display home icon.

But there some reason I want to put `home` as variable, something like this:

```
let homeIcon = 'home';
<i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">{homeIcon}</i>
```

Is there the way to do like that?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so, please, provide feedback with either accepting answer or comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use material icons using any of these variants:
`<i class="material-icons">face</i>`
and
`<i class="material-icons">&#xE87C;</i>`

I think that your variable doesnt transfer to ligatures, showing `home` as is instead. Try to do something like `const iconHome = <i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">home</i>;` or use numeric char reference.

This example uses a typographic feature called ligatures, which allows rendering of an icon glyph simply by using its textual name. The replacement is done automatically by the web browser and provides more readable code than the equivalent numeric character reference.
Additionally you want to check special thin wrapper over material-components for preact: [preact-material](https://github.com/prateekbh/preact-material-components)

For reference: [Material Icons](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)

Comment: Thank you for giving some good workarounds.
I manage to solve the issue by put `home` to a function instead of variable. 
Something like this: `<i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">getHomeIcon()</i>`. Finally, it works.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try using a template literal

`` <i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">{`${homeIcon}`}</i> ``